# How should I do to replace the double quotation mark following a number only?

Tags: java, replaceall

For example, the target string is: `AAA"AAA"AAAA 18" x 18" bbb""`.
The target string after replacement should be : `AAA"AAA"AAAA 18 inches x 18 inches bbb""`.

Comment: What did you try? (see also how to ask in the help section)

Comment: First thought: Regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have the following [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "AAA\"AAA\"AAAA 18\" x 18\" bbb\"\"";
    String replaced = str.replaceAll("(\\d+)\"", "$1 inches");
    System.out.println(replaced); // prints AAA"AAA"AAAA 18 inches x 18 inches bbb""
}
```

This code replaces all digits followed by a quote `"` with those digits (using the [back reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) `$1`) and `inches`. As such, this makes sure that only quotes after digits are replaced.